# React Native Expo-Camera recording video find problem User rejected audio permission needed

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, expo, expo-camera

I'm having trouble recording video with expo-camera. User rejected audio permission needed. Has anyone had such a problem?? If anyone tells me the way to solve the problem, I also added expo install expo-permissions. But it still doesn't work
taking snap working fine just problem through recoding video...Here is my code.

```
   import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
    import {
      StyleSheet,
      Dimensions,
      View,
      Text,
      TouchableOpacity,
      SafeAreaView,
    } from "react-native";
    import { Camera } from "expo-camera";
    import { Video } from "expo-av";
    const WINDOW_HEIGHT = Dimensions.get("window").height;
    const closeButtonSize = Math.floor(WINDOW_HEIGHT * 0.032);
    const captureSize = Math.floor(WINDOW_HEIGHT * 0.09);
    export default function App() {
      const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(null);
      const [cameraType, setCameraType] = useState(Camera.Constants.Type.back);
      const [isPreview, setIsPreview] = useState(false);
      const [isCameraReady, setIsCameraReady] = useState(false);
      const [isVideoRecording, setIsVideoRecording] = useState(false);
      const [videoSource, setVideoSource] = useState(null);
      const cameraRef = useRef();
      useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
          const { status } = await Camera.requestPermissionsAsync()
          setHasPermission(status === "granted");
        })();
      }, []);
      const onCameraReady = () => {
        setIsCameraReady(true);
      };
      const takePicture = async () => {
        if (cameraRef.current) {
          const options = { quality: 0.5, base64: true, skipProcessing: true };
          const data = await cameraRef.current.takePictureAsync(options);
          const source = data.uri;
          if (source) {
            await cameraRef.current.pausePreview();
            setIsPreview(true);
            console.log("picture source", source);
          }
        }
      };
      const recordVideo = async () => {
        if (cameraRef.current) {
          try {
            const videoRecordPromise = cameraRef.current.recordAsync();
            if (videoRecordPromise) {
              setIsVideoRecording(true);
              const data = await videoRecordPromise;
              const source = data.uri;
              if (source) {
                setIsPreview(true);
                console.log("video source", source);
                setVideoSource(source);
              }
            }
          } catch (error) {
            console.warn(error);
          }
        }
      };
      const stopVideoRecording = () => {
        if (cameraRef.current) {
          setIsPreview(false);
          setIsVideoRecording(false);
          cameraRef.current.stopRecording();
        }
      };
      const switchCamera = () => {
        if (isPreview) {
          return;
        }
        setCameraType((prevCameraType) =>
          prevCameraType === Camera.Constants.Type.back
            ? Camera.Constants.Type.front
            : Camera.Constants.Type.back
        );
      };
      const cancelPreview = async () => {
        await cameraRef.current.resumePreview();
        setIsPreview(false);
        setVideoSource(null);
      };
      const renderCancelPreviewButton = () => (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={cancelPreview} style={styles.closeButton}>
          <View style={[styles.closeCross, { transform: [{ rotate: "45deg" }] }]} />
          <View
            style={[styles.closeCross, { transform: [{ rotate: "-45deg" }] }]}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      );
      const renderVideoPlayer = () => (
        <Video
          source={{ uri: videoSource }}
          shouldPlay={true}
          style={styles.media}
        />
      );
      const renderVideoRecordIndicator = () => (
        <View style={styles.recordIndicatorContainer}>
          <View style={styles.recordDot} />
          <Text style={styles.recordTitle}>{"Recording..."}</Text>
        </View>
      );
      const renderCaptureControl = () => (
        <View style={styles.control}>
          <TouchableOpacity disabled={!isCameraReady} onPress={switchCamera}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>{"Flip"}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity
            activeOpacity={0.7}
            disabled={!isCameraReady}
            onLongPress={recordVideo}
            onPressOut={stopVideoRecording}
            onPress={takePicture}
            style={styles.capture}
          />
        </View>
      );
      if (hasPermission === null) {
        return <View />;
      }
      if (hasPermission === false) {
        return <Text style={styles.text}>No access to camera</Text>;
      }
      return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
          <Camera
            ref={cameraRef}
            style={styles.container}
            type={cameraType}
            flashMode={Camera.Constants.FlashMode.on}
            onCameraReady={onCameraReady}
    
            onMountError={(error) => {
              console.log("cammera error", error);
            }}
            
          />
          <View style={styles.container}>
            {isVideoRecording && renderVideoRecordIndicator()}
            {videoSource && renderVideoPlayer()}
            {isPreview && renderCancelPreviewButton()}
            {!videoSource && !isPreview && renderCaptureControl()}
          </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
      );
    }
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
      },
      closeButton: {
        position: "absolute",
        top: 35,
        left: 15,
        height: closeButtonSize,
        width: closeButtonSize,
        borderRadius: Math.floor(closeButtonSize / 2),
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        backgroundColor: "#c4c5c4",
        opacity: 0.7,
        zIndex: 2,
      },
      media: {
        ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
      },
      closeCross: {
        width: "68%",
        height: 1,
        backgroundColor: "black",
      },
      control: {
        position: "absolute",
        flexDirection: "row",
        bottom: 38,
        width: "100%",
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
      },
      capture: {
        backgroundColor: "#f5f6f5",
        borderRadius: 5,
        height: captureSize,
        width: captureSize,
        borderRadius: Math.floor(captureSize / 2),
        marginHorizontal: 31,
      },
      recordIndicatorContainer: {
        flexDirection: "row",
        position: "absolute",
        top: 25,
        alignSelf: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        backgroundColor: "transparent",
        opacity: 0.7,
      },
      recordTitle: {
        fontSize: 14,
        color: "#ffffff",
        textAlign: "center",
      },
      recordDot: {
        borderRadius: 3,
        height: 6,
        width: 6,
        backgroundColor: "#ff0000",
        marginHorizontal: 5,
      },
      text: {
        color: "#fff",
      },
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `expo-camera` with `expo-av` you can do something like that:

```
const getPermissions = useCallback(
        async () => {
            const { status } = await Camera.requestPermissionsAsync();
            await Audio.requestPermissionsAsync();
            await Audio.setAudioModeAsync({
                allowsRecordingIOS: true,
                playsInSilentModeIOS: true,
            });
            setHasPermission(status === 'granted');
        },
        [sound, hasPermission],
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Now in the expo camera, we have to ask for mic permission separately from the user. You can update your code like this:

```
const [hasCameraPermission, setHasCameraPermission] = useState(false);
const [hasMicPermission, setHasMicPermission] = useState(false);

useEffect(()=>{
(async () => {
const camStatus = await Camera.requestCameraPermissionsAsync();
if (camStatus.granted){
    sethasCameraPermission(true)
}
const micStatus = await Camera.requestMicrophonePermissionsAsync();
if (micStatus.granted){
    setHasMicPermission(true);}
})();
},[])
```